# Using NUT to manage a UPS during coastal storms

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a UPS power management system for a coastal property that not only protects against routine (short) power outages, but has specific behavior when put in 'storm mode' for a major event (e.g. hurricane).

The idea is to have a Raspberry Pi connected by USB to the UPS running the NUT monitoring services. In 'storm mode', upon line power loss, the Pi is to run the UPS for 5 minutes every hour - long enough to get weather data, capture some photos from exterior cameras and upload that via an LTE hotspot to a web server (or if there is no cell service, store it on disk for later uploading).

I had originally thought to have a UPS capable of running the equipment continuously for 24-48 hours, but even though the power draw is not much, the UPS itself (no load) will only run 4-5 hours. Running for 5 minutes per hour should easily run for 2-3 days.

The question is, is it possible to turn the UPS on/off via the NUT services. I can find scant information on exactly what NUT is capable of and what some of the variables actually mean (e.g. ups.timer.shutdown). Are common UPS's such as the CyberPower CP1500PFCLCD capable of this (e.g. responding to USB commands after being turned off so an external controller can turn them back on even without line power)? Is this scheme feasible with common UPS equipment?

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but [ask]

Comment: The tag `ups` is for UPS the *shipping services provider*, not Uninterruptible Power Supply

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation is appears this is feasible - the NUT documentation is very detailed on commands and parameters, but little on how to actually accomplish anything other than automate computer shutdown sequences.

The Pi itself can be powered from the UPS and with proper delays it can coordinate its own (and other equipment) power off and later power back on. Implementation could be in a shell script, Java, or other language of choice but the key sequence to power up for 5 minutes every hour is something like:

```
1. Pi boots and stabilizes
2. Collect environment data (weather conditions, flood sensors, camera photos) for 5 minutes
3. If internet connection (LTE hotspot) is ready, post to hosted web server else save to disk
4. Issue UPS command "load.off.delay 70" which schedules the power to go off in 70 seconds (enough time to complete the following steps)
5. If UPS status is "LB" (low battery) issue UPS command "shutdown.return" and shutdown the Pi. In 70 seconds the system is dead until power comes back on.
6. Issue UPS command "load.on.delay 3300" to schedule the UPS to turn on in 55 minutes. (There are now 2 scheduled events stored in the UPS)
7. Run an orderly shutdown of the Pi.
8. The UPS will turn off in 70 seconds, then turn back on in 55 minutes, repeat from #1.
```

The key to all this is that the UPS is capable of scheduling power on and power off events independently and when the load is turned off, it takes very little power for the UPS to keep its scheduler running. It should be able to run this sequence for at least 24 hours, maybe much longer.